# How to send a notification to my android app through my already-made website, that isn't a web app by google

Tags: javascript, php, html, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I already have my website built. I decided to make an app to broadcast a notification to all users and give them a score update for my high school, I cannot find any sources on how to implement code into my previous-built website. My website is not a firebase web app. I want to be able to click the "Touchdown" button and it will send a notification to everyone with a title of "Blah scored a touchdown!", and a body of "Blah 42 - Blah2.0 41" Any help will be much appreciated!

Update:
My website: www.yorkcougars.com
My website is a site that people can go to to get scores, roster, team records, live scoring, etc. of my high school football team. I created an app so that way I can send notifications to people's phones whenever a team scores. So I want it to be where when I click on "Touchdown" it will send a notification to everyone's phone giving them a score update.

P.S. I am new to this, so I apologize in advance for bad communication skills, and/or lack of clarification!

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you currently have built? Telling us that your website is NOT a firebase web app isn't very helpful, it would be more useful to tell us what your website is :P

Comment: @katamaster818, My website: www.yorkcougars.com My website is a site that people can go to to get scores, roster, team records, live scoring, etc. of my high school football team. I created an app so that way I can send notifications to people's phones whenever a team scores. So I want it to be where when I click on "Touchdown" it will send a notification to everyone's phone giving them a score update.

Comment: It's not a very straightforward process; but you could create a free Firebase account and use the Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) service to deliver push notifications to both iOS and Android Apps. Your app would include the library to listen for notifications, and your web site would call the FCM API to request that a message be pushed.

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-firebase-messaging-for-ios--cms-32126
https://medium.com/@anum.amin/react-native-integrating-push-notifications-using-fcm-349fff071591
https://sandny.com/2019/03/11/fcm-push-notification-react-native/